Requests cert parameter is not clearing
I am having an issue with the python requests library persisting the certificate passed in a previous call into a future call. When making the first call to an external API I get a normal bad token error message. I then make a call that passes a certificate via the cert=cert line in requests which returns okay as well. I then make a third call to the same url as the first one and it responds with "400 The SSL certificate error". This seems to be the server rejecting the certificate which I am not passing, and the requests are not sharing a session.
Here is example code that I use to reproduce this issue but with valid certificate values in cert.
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://auth.smaapis.de/oauth2/token'
    cert = ('example_cert.pem', 'example_cert_key.pem')

    response = requests.post(url)
    print('Before Response: {} {}: {}\n'.format(response.status_code, response.reason, response.text))

    response = requests.get('https://google.com', cert=cert)

    response = requests.post(url)
    print('After Response:  {} {}: {}\n'.format(response.status_code, response.reason, response.text))

Before Response: 400 invalid_request: Missing form parameter: grant_type
After Response: 400 The SSL certificate error

If the middle request is commented out the last request starts getting the normal error again and not the 400 SSL error. I have done some debugging, and it seems to be due to the ssl_context object in requests/adapters.py being reused for all requests calls.
Sharing a session without popping it seems to be making it work which seems counter-intuitive but this isn't an option for my actual code:
import requests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://auth.smaapis.de/oauth2/token'
    cert = ('example_cert.pem', 'example_cert_key.pem')

    session = requests.Session()

    request = session.post(url)
    print('Before Response: {} {}: {}\n'.format(response.status_code, response.reason, response.text))

    request = session.get('https://google.com', cert=cert)

    request = session.post(url)
    print('After Response:  {} {}: {}\n'.format(response.status_code, response.reason, response.text))

Before Response: 400 invalid_request: Missing form parameter: grant_type
After Response:  400 invalid_request: Missing form parameter: grant_type

This is only happening after the latest version of requests 2.32 but it wasn't happening on 2.31
I am avoiding setting verify=False because I still want to require the standard certifi certificates. Could this be a possible bug in requests or is there a concept with this that I assumed incorrectly?

In your first example, the code has print('Before Request: ... but the given output is Before Response: ... These do not match.  Please post the real code.

Updated, thanks!

It seems that version 2.32.0 (2024-05-20) has introduced this "undocumented behaviour". The Release History mentions the change you already pointed out:
"Improvements - verify=True now reuses a global SSLContext which should improve request time variance between first and subsequent requests. It should also minimize certificate load time on Windows systems when using a Python version built with OpenSSL 3.x. (#6667)"

Did some additional testing and now can confirm your findings: in version 2.31.0 it works, from version 2.32.0 on the third request sends the client certificate which only the second request should use.

I could reproduce the "undocumented behaviour" you described.
In version 2.31.0 it works as expected, from version 2.32.0 on it is broken.
The problem seems to be (as you suspected) in the following change (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community/updates/#id4):

Improvements - verify=True now reuses a global SSLContext which should improve request time variance between first and subsequent
requests. It should also minimize certificate load time on Windows
systems when using a Python version built with OpenSSL 3.x. (#6667)

A similar issue (https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6726) and even a suggested patch (https://github.com/psf/requests/commit/fe251aa94b2b7849e224e455c0aad0df53ad3d8e) can be found on the Github of requests.
The patch only uses the global ssl_context if no client certificate is present by adding the last line in the following code snippet:
should_use_default_ssl_context = (
    verify is True
    and _preloaded_ssl_context is not None
    and not has_poolmanager_ssl_context
    and client_cert is None
)

Unfortunately the patch has not made it into the main branch yet.
UPDATE: I tested requests version 2.32.3 with the manually added patched adapters.py and it worked as expected.
